# How can I only raise the red Numbers (0x00ff0000) of RGB by a value like 10%?

Tags: java, pixel

```java
class TestFilter extends RGBImageFilter {

    public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int pixel) { //0xffffffff
        

        float redfilteredPixel;
        int restPixel;

        redfilteredPixel = (pixel & 0x00ff0000); //red pixel
        restPixel = (pixel & 0xff00ffff); //"restpixel"

        redfilteredPixel *= 1.1f;

        int redpixel = (int) redfilteredPixel & 0x00ff0000;
        
        return (redpixel | restPixel);
    }
}
```

It is for a school project, but I should only change the middle part of the method.

Comment: What do you mean "raise by 10%"?

Comment: If you mean "Increase the red channel value by 10 %", then shift it to the right, then do the calculus, don't forget to chop off overflow, shift back to "red" position and "or in" the rest again.

Comment: so lets say I got a pixel with 0x05124356 as RGB, but I would like to have the RED-Part in this example only  the 12 in hexa value increased by 10%

Comment: `00` is 0, `FF` is 255 (simple hexadecimal conversion).  Convert he value and then the operation is simple.

Comment: oof, you are right.. I thought it is 16*16*16*16*16 because of hexa..

Comment: As an alternative, you could also use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html , parse the int value to it, getRed, *1.1 , Max(255) , create new Color with respective components, getRGB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you wrote this pretty much works already.  The problem is what happens when the result is too big to fit in the 8 bits you have for the red field.

You can just add a check after you convert back to int, like this:

```
    int redpixel = (int) redfilteredPixel & 0x00ff0000;
    if (redpixel > 0x00FF0000)
        redpixel = 0x00FF0000;
```

That will *work*, but it's a little unusual.  Normally code for doing this would not convert to float.

Also, it would be easier to understand if you converted the red value all the way to an int in [0,255], but it isn't necessary to do that in this case (+10% works the same either way), and usually when you're writing low-level pixel code like this it's better to do it the fast way.

Answer (score 0):

Out of my head, it should be something like this:

```
//shift the bytes to only get the red value as a numerical value
int redValue = redfilteredPixel >> 16;
redValue *= 1.1f;
//make sure it doesnt exceed 255 after the multiplication
redValue = Math.min(255, redValue);
//shift the bytes back to the correct place
redfilteredPixel = redValue << 16;
```

Comment: You need to shift by 16